# Page could not be rendered error while viewing YAP using listings package

Tags: listings, code

I cannot view the DVI output in YAP, as it shows the below error (The page could not be rendered) if I use the listings package.

Could any one suggest me how to solve this error?

[image]

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Also, please review your previous questions... You have received many useful answers, but you didn't accept any. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) if you don't know how to do.

Comment: In your code you have division by zero, e.g. `0 0 div` which is not possible. And which my mot be a problem of `listings`.

Comment: Sorry to mention it, I also used figures in this chapter. If I removed the figures I can view the DVI without any problem. So, there is no problem with listings. Thank u for your help.....